# Is it possible to modify the behavior of len()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm aware of creating a custom `__repr__` or `__add__` method (and so on), to modify the behavior of operators and functions. Is there a method override for `len`?

For example:

```
class Foo:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "A wild Foo Class in its natural habitat."

foo = Foo()

print(foo)         # A wild Foo Class in its natural habitat.
print(repr(foo))   # A wild Foo Class in its natural habitat.
```

Could this be done for `len`, with a list? Normally, it would look like this:

```
foo = []
print(len(foo))    # 0

foo = [1, 2, 3]
print(len(foo))    # 3
```

What if I want to leave search types out of the count? Like this:

```
class Bar(list):
    pass

foo = [Bar(), 1, '']
print(len(foo))    # 3

count = 0
for item in foo:
    if not isinstance(item, Bar):
        count += 1

print(count)       # 2
```

Is there a way to do this from within a `list` subclass?

Comment: You already have good answers, but in case you want to find out more about magic methods I can suggest [A Guide to Python's Magic Methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) ;)

Comment: This will come in handy quite a bit! Thanks for sharing. @swenzel

Comment: You have a list subclass, not a list superclass.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, implement the [`__len__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__):

```
def __len__(self):
    return 42
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __len__(self):
...         return 42
... 
>>> len(Foo())
42
```

From the documentation:

> Called to implement the built-in function `len()`. Should return the length of the object, an integer `>=` 0. Also, an object that doesn’t define a `__bool__()` method and whose `__len__()` method returns zero is considered to be false in a Boolean context.

For your specific case:

```
>>> class Bar(list):
...     def __len__(self):
...         return sum(1 for ob in self if not isinstance(ob, Bar))
... 
>>> len(Bar([1, 2, 3]))
3
>>> len(Bar([1, 2, 3, Bar()]))
3
```

Comment: Would `sum(not isinstance(ob, Bar) for ob in self)` be a bit cleaner?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: at which point you have to explain that Python's boolean type is a subclass of int and that `True` has an integer value of 1 and `False` a value of 0. It's not always worth having a little bit less code when you have to explain that every single time.

Comment: Very true; I hadn't thought of it that way.

Comment: Note, `__len__` doesn't need to return an integer. A non-integer will usually return an error of "object cannot be interpreted as an integer", but if the result of `__len__` has an `__index__` method, builtin `len` (the `len` that calls `__len__`) will happily just return the value returned by `__index__`. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0357/. Note that builtin `len` also does a check and throws an error if the value is less than 0. Also for `not x`, if x does not have a `__bool__` function defined but has `__len__`, `__len__` is called and the x is treated as False iff len(x) == 0

Answer (score 7):

Yes, just as you have already discovered that you can override the behaviour of a `repr()` function call by implementing the `__repr__` magic method, you can specify the behaviour from a [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) function call by implementing (surprise surprise) then [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) magic:

```
>>> class Thing:
...     def __len__(self):
...         return 123
...     
>>> len(Thing())
123
```

A pedant might mention that you are not modifying the behaviour of `len()`, you are modifying the behaviour of your class.  `len` just does the same thing it always does, which includes checking for a `__len__` attribute on the argument.

Answer (score 5):

Remember: [Python](https://www.python.org) is a dynamically and [Duck Typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) language.

*If it acts like something that might have a length;*

```
class MyCollection(object):

    def __len__(self):
        return 1234
```

Example:

```
>>> obj = MyCollection()
>>> len(obj)
1234
```

*if it doesn't act like it has a length;* **KABOOM!**

```
class Foo(object):

    def __repr___(self):
        return "<Foo>"
```

Example:

```
>>> try:
...     obj = Foo()
...     len(obj)
... except:
...     raise
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'Foo' has no len()
```

From [Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29#Typing):

> Python uses duck typing and has typed objects but untyped variable
>   names. Type constraints are not checked at compile time; rather,
>   operations on an object may fail, signifying that the given object is
>   not of a suitable type. Despite being dynamically typed, Python is
>   strongly typed, forbidding operations that are not well-defined (for
>   example, adding a number to a string) rather than silently attempting
>   to make sense of them.

Example:

```
>>> x = 1234
>>> s = "1234"
>>> x + s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just add a `__len__` method to your class.

```
class Test:
    def __len__(self):
        return 2

a=Test()
len(a) # --> 2
```